# how to append a singleton numpy array item into a list?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pytorch

I am attaching the code first which will give you a better idea

```
`   prediction = prediction.data.max(1)[1] #gives a tensor value
    prediction = (prediction.cpu().numpy().item()) #converts that tensor into a numpy array 
    result.append(int_to_word[prediction])`
```

I am using pytorch for word generation. The line `prediction = prediction.data.max(1)[1]` gives us the class label with the maximum probability, which turns out to be a  tensor value.

`prediction = (prediction.cpu().numpy().item())` this statement converts the tensor into a numpy array and the funtion `item()` extracts the value from the array.

Now when I try to append this value using `pattern.append(prediction)`
I am getting the following error
`'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'`

I am not able to understand as to why I am getting this error. I have already converted the numpy array into a scalr value, didn't I?? Still, why am I getting that error?

Can anybody please explain and provide a solution to this. I would be most grateful.

Comment: it looks like your `result` (from which you call the method `.append`) is the `numpy.ndarray`, while probably you are expecting it to be a list. Try to initialize it as a list, or use `numpy.concat`

Comment: hey thanks for the comment. It seems like prediction was a class numpy .ndarray.  I converted it to list using `.tolist() ` function. Now its working like a charm. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy arrays are *immutable* with respect to their dimensions. They do not support the `append` operation. You'll have to declare `results` as a list, then append your values to your list, and then convert it to a numpy array:

```
result = []
...

result.append(prediction) # inside some loop

...

result = np.array(result)
```